# plt.savefig produces blank figure in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to save a plot as a png. The following code produces a blank figure:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace (0 , 10, 1000)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.savefig('line_plot.png', dpi=100)
```

I am using Python 3.6 together with Anaconda and Spyder 3.2.0. How can I get a png containing the desired plot?

Comment: You say that you want to save your plot as `png`, but in your code it says `'line_plot.jpg'` -- are you sure that you are looking at the right file?

Comment: Thank you. I changed it.

Comment: The code from the question should run fine. When I run it it produces the [desired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmnh2.png).

Comment: Are you running Python 3.6 together with Anaconda and Spyder 3.2.0. on windows 7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the Figure object directly.

```
fig=plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)
fig.savefig('line_plot.png', dpi=100)
```

If you are interested in a PNG use '.png' instead of '.jpg'. Depending on the GUI toolkit you may need to add fig.show() before the last line.

Comment: I had the same problem and this worked, thanks. It is hard to understand why you have to do this though. I would classify this as a bug not a feature.